# how to change text of button in redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Hi all i need to change text of my button when it's done.I want to use redux and es6. Right now my code is.

```
var TodoItem = React.createClass({
handleCompleted: function() {
this.props.completeTodo(this.props.todo.id);
},
handleDelete: function() {
this.props.deleteTodo(this.props.todo.id);
},
render: function() {
var textStyle = this.renderTextStyle();
return (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div style={textStyle}>
        {this.props.todo.text}
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.handleCompleted}>toggle completed</button>
      <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>delete</button>
```

[To do app **I **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uR3f.png)

Comment: I have attached pic( To do app **| ** ) that what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a value in your state that you can bind your button's text to. For example, if you have a `todo.isComplete` boolean, you can do something like this:

```
<button onClick={this.handleCompleted}>{ this.props.todo.isComplete ? 'undo' : 'complete' }</button>
```

Your reducer can set the `todo.isComplete` value.